# mysql update with form

Tags: php, javascript, html

Having trouble where I think I need to provide most of my code to see what is happening.  Trying to output a simple table of cameras.  They are stored as part of a form which a user can change and hit the apply button. The changes should update the db.  The problem is that when I hit apply it doesn't update any of the rows. The exception is the very last row (last camera in the list).

As you can see I echo certain variables and they seem fine.  Completely confused...

```
<?php 
// Dont allow direct linking
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Direct Access to this location is not allowed.');
//get current user
$user =& JFactory::getUser();
// get a reference to the database
$db = &JFactory::getDBO();

if (isset($_POST['apply_changes'])) {

    //process changes to camera options     
    $camera_id = (int) $_POST['camera_id'];
    echo "CAMERA ID ".$camera_id;
    $camera_status = check_input($_POST['camera_status']);
    echo "CAMERA STATUS ".$camera_status;
    $camera_name = check_input($_POST['camera_name']);
    $camera_quality = check_input($_POST['camera_quality']);

    $query_insert_camera = 'UPDATE `#__cameras` SET `camera_status` ="'.$camera_status.'" WHERE `camera_id`='.$camera_id;
    echo "CAMERA query ".$query_insert_camera;
    $db->setQuery($query_insert_camera);
    $db->query();
}

function check_input($data, $problem='')
{
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    if ($problem && strlen($data) == 0)
    {
        show_error($problem);
    }
    return $data;
}

function show_error($myError)
{
    echo $myError;
    exit();
}   

echo "<html>";
echo "<head>";

?>

<script type="text/javascript">
function oncameraSubmit(camera_id)
{
 //TODO get camera name i.e.  "Apply changes to <camera name>"
  document.active_cameras.camera_id.value = camera_id;
  return confirm('Apply changes?');
}
</script>
<?php
$query_camera_name = "SELECT camera_id, camera_name, camera_status, camera_quality, camera_hash, camera_type FROM #__cameras WHERE user_id=".$user->id." AND camera_status!='DELETED'";
$db->setQuery($query_camera_name);
//get number of cameras so we can build the table accordingly
$db->query();
$num_rows = $db->getNumRows();
// We can use array names with loadAssocList.
$result_cameras = $db->loadAssocList(); 

echo "</head>";
echo "<body>";

//check if we have cameras running (basically someone logged in)
if (!isset($result_cameras))
{
    //TODO check if query failed
}
else 
{

    if ($num_rows == 0)
    {           
        echo '<b><i><center>You currently have no cameras setup.  Add a Camera below.</center></i></b>';
    }
    else
    {
        ?>
        <form name="active_cameras" action="<?php htmlentities($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="camera_id" value="" />
        <table id="webcam-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Camera Type</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Quality</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Camera Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
<?php
        for($i=0;$i<$num_rows;$i++)
        {

            //camera_status
            if ($result_cameras[$i]["camera_status"] == "ENABLED")
            {
                $enabled_option =  "value='ENABLED' selected='selected'"; 
                $disabled_option = "value='DISABLED'";
            }
            else
            {
                $enabled_option =  "value='ENABLED'";
                $disabled_option = "value='DISABLED' selected='selected'";
            }

            //camera_quality
            if ($result_cameras[$i]["camera_quality"] == "HIGH")
            {
                $high_option =  "value='HIGH' selected='selected'"; 
                $medium_option = "value='MEDIUM'";
                $mobile_option =  "value='MOBILE'";
            }
            else if ($result_cameras[$i]["camera_quality"] == "MEDIUM")
            {
                $high_option =  "value='HIGH'";
                $medium_option = "value='MEDIUM' selected='selected'";
                $mobile_option =  "value='MOBILE'";
            }
            else if ($result_cameras[$i]["camera_quality"] == "MOBILE")
            {
                $high_option =  "value='HIGH'";
                $medium_option = "value='MEDIUM'";
                $mobile_option =  "value='MOBILE' selected='selected'";
            }
            else
            {
                //TODO proper logging
            }

            //camera_type
            if ($result_cameras[$i]["camera_type"] == "WEBCAM")
            {
                $webcam =  "value='WEBCAM' selected='selected'"; 
                $axis = "value='AXIS'";
                $other =  "value='IPCAM'";
            }
            else if ($result_cameras[$i]["camera_type"] == "AXIS")
            {
                $webcam =  "value='WEBCAM'";
                $axis = "value='AXIS' selected='selected'";
                $other =  "value='IPCAM'";
            }
            else if ($result_cameras[$i]["camera_type"] == "IPCAM")
            {
                $webcam =  "value='WEBCAM'";
                $axis = "value='AXIS'";
                $other =  "value='IPCAM' selected='selected'";
            }
            else
            {
                //TODO proper logging
            }
            echo $result_cameras[$i]["camera_id"];

?> 

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $result_cameras[$i]["camera_type"] ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                <input type="text" size="32" maxlength="64" name="camera_name" value="<?php echo $result_cameras[$i]["camera_name"]; ?>" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select name="camera_quality">
                    <option <?php echo $high_option; ?>>High</option>
                    <option <?php echo $medium_option; ?>>Medium</option>
                    <option <?php echo $mobile_option; ?>>Mobile</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select name="camera_status">
                    <option <?php echo $enabled_option; ?>>Enabled</option>
                    <option <?php echo $disabled_option; ?>>Disabled</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" name="apply_changes" value="Apply" onClick="oncameraSubmit(<?php echo $result_cameras[$i]["camera_id"]; ?>);"/>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete" onClick="oncameraDelete(<?php echo $result_cameras[$i]["camera_id"]; ?>);"/>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <input type="submit" name="video" value="Launch" onClick="oncameraLaunch(<?php echo $result_cameras[$i]["camera_id"]; ?>);"/>

                </td>
            </tr>

            <?php
        }

        echo "</tbody>";
        echo "</table>";
        echo "</form>";
    }
}


echo "</body>";
echo "</html>";

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update query should be (Use single quote for non-numeric value),

```
$query_insert_camera ="UPDATE `#__cameras` 
     SET `camera_status` ='$camera_status' WHERE `camera_id`=$camera_id";
```

Comment: Fixed that but still the same issue.  I can see that when I echo the query that camera_status does not have the right value. Why is this value not right? [code]$camera_status = check_input($_POST['camera_status']);[/code]